# can we create datagridview user control in winforms?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I am new to winforms and I want to create a datagridview user control. can we create datagridview user control in winforms ?  I googled but didn't find any resources.. any inputs would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: What do you mean by DataGridView UserControl?

Comment: reusable datagrid control... I want to create a user control with datagrid and I want to use that in other forms..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a UserControl, put a DataGridView on it using drag and drop from ToolBox, Then customize your DataGridView, Build the project and you can select the UserControl from the ToolBox and use it where ever you want.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) is a walkthrough in C# to start using UserControls.

**Edit:**

To bind data to your UserControl you can expose the DataGridView's DataSource property. Suppose on your UserControl you have a DataGridView named dataGridView1 :

```
public class UcMyCustomizedGridView : UserControl
{
   public object DataSource 
   {
        get{ return dataGridView1.DataSource;}
        set{ dataGridView1.DataSource = value;}
    }

    public UcMyCustomizedGridView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In your form you can bind data to the UserControl like this:

```
IEnumerable list;
// fill the list with your data
ucMyCustomizedGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: thanks for the link, how can I access the usercontrol from winform ?? I cretaed usercontrol with datagrid and placed it in my winform, but unable to bind data to it.. how can I do it ?